# Where to find LinkedHashSet in jsinterop?

Tags: gwt, linkedhashset, gwt-jsinterop

I have the following entity in GWT

```
@JsType(namespace = "my.entities")
public class MyEntity {
   private Set<String> texts;
   public Set<String> getTexts(){
       if(this.texts==null)
           this.texts=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
       return this.texts;
   }

   public void setTexts(Set<String> texts){
       this.texts=texts;
   }

}
```

When I call `myEntityVar.getTexts()` in Javascript the returned object is a HashSet. It seems like jsinterop converts the java implementation of HashSet to JavaScript. But how can I create a new HashSet in JavaScript in order to use `myEntityVar.setTexts(texts)`? I tried an array for the "texts" param, but that doesn't work. So I somehow need to use HashSet in JavaScript. 
However, I can't figure out, where to find it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that you can't - but then again, you also can't create a plain HashSet in JS either!

The reason that this works at all is that you've enabled `-generateJsInteropExports`, and while there is a JsInterop annotation on your `MyEntity` type, there is also one on `java.util.Set` (and a few other base JRE types). This allows for your code to return emulated java Sets without issue - any method which is compatible with running in JS is supported.

There are a few downsides:

- Compiled size increases somewhat, since even if you don't use a method, it must be compiled in to your app this way, just in case JS uses it
- Some methods are not supported - JS doesn't really have method overloading, so `toArray()` and `toArray(T[])` look like the same method in JS. GWT solves this by not supporting the second method at all. (`java.util.List` has the same issue with `remove(T)` and `remove(int)`, but it resolves it by renaming `remove(int)` to `removeAtIndex(int)` when compiled.)

If you never return these types, you'll probably want to disable this feature entirely - the `-excludeJsInteropExports` and `-includeJsInteropExports` flags to the compiler let you control what is exported.

---

To answer your question more directly, you have a few options that I can see:

- Allow the `setTexts` method to be passed something else from JS, such as a `JsArrayLike` so that you could let users pass in a plain JS array of strings, or even a JS Set. You could go further and accept `Object`, and then type-check it to see what was passed in. You could even leave the `Set` override so it could be called from your own Java if necessary, but mark it as `@JsIgnore` so that GWT doesn't break when you attempt to export overloaded methods.
- Create a factory method somewhere to create the Set implementation you would like your JS users to use. Since `add` and `remove` are supported, the calling JS code can build up the set before passing it in. Something like this:

  ```
  @JsMethod(namespace = "my.Util")
  public static <T> LinkedHashSet<T> createSet() {
    return new LinkedHashSet<>();
  }
  ```

  Now they can call `my.Util.createSet()`, append items, and then pass it to your setTexts method.